# Way to survey Chrome open tabs in javascript that's not in an extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, tabs

Background: Mac application Keyboard Maestro allows a macro to run arbitrary javascript in Google Chrome. I would have such a macro run every N seconds while Chrome is running.

I often have (a) tab(s) open, although not necessarily selected, which time out and are replaced by a login form after an interval without user interaction. I want to prevent this.

For each browser tab having a name or URL that matches a search criterion, I want to perform an action on it that would prevent a timeout. For now, I'm assuming that would be a page reload.

I'm not a web developer and don't know what will work where. E.g., chrome.tabs seems to be for use within extensions.

I tried this, which I found on SO, but it appeared not to do anything:

```
    chrome.tabs.query({windowType:'normal'}, function(tabs) {
        for(var i = 0; i < tabs.length; i++) {
            chrome.tabs.update(tabs[i].id, {url: tabs[i].url});
        }
    });
```